# Abstract title has disappeared

Tags: abstract, aiaa

I was trying to change the name of the Abstact to Summary. I tried `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Summary}`. That did not work, so I removed that line. And now the abstract title has completely disappeared. I'm using TexStudio. Its also disappeared in other documents using the same class. Also the `\affil` command is no longer recognized. I've included a picture of the output.

Thanks for you suggestions.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[conf]{new-aiaa}
%\documentclass[journal]{new-aiaa} for journal papers



\title{No Abstract}

\author{N. O. Abstract}}
\affil{USA}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Where is my abstract title?
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `new-aiaa` is not on ctan. Can you provide a link to that class (.cls) file?

Comment: Is this it? https://github.com/Flyingbobcats/journal/blob/master/new-aiaa.cls?

Comment: Its on overleaf. Here's a link: https://www.overleaf.com/project/5dcee234aa75070001f17dde

Yes thats it.

Comment: @NoA ”Restricted, sorry you don't have permission to load this page.” For my answer I used the link given by Matthias Arras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class does

```latex
\RequirePackage[style]{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstitlestyle}[1]{}
```

The default definition in `abstract.sty` is

```latex
\renewcommand{\abstitlestyle}[1]{#1}
```

and the `abstract` environment does

```latex
\abstitlestyle{\abstractname}
```

On the other hand the class also does

```latex
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\bfseries\normalsize}
```

which is meant to print the abstract in bold face.

I conclude that these are *deliberate* choices and you shouldn't try and modify them.

Comment: I fully agree with egreg, that this is likely not what should be done if you intent to submit this as an abstract. However, as you can make your own choices: adding  `\renewcommand{\abstitlestyle}[1]{#1}` and `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Summary}` to the preamble portion of your document works for me. Not saying that it looks particularly enticing. But the choice is yours.

Comment: I agree its unorthodox and maybe a dumb question. But I'm submitting the same document to two different things with different style guidelines, and just want to quickly change the abstract heading. Not planning to make a habit of it. These two answers are what I needed though, so thanks.